# Office 365 Add Index to FileRef and UniqueId

Tags: office-365, index

I am trying to add indexes to the Title, FileRef and UniqueId fields in my library to avoid a list query threshold error.  My code is as follows:

```
private void CreateListIndexes()
    {
        var list = ClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(AppConstants.Office365SourceDocuments);
        ClientContext.Load(list);
        ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        CreateListIndex(list, "Title");
        CreateListIndex(list, "FileRef");
        CreateListIndex(list, "UniqueId");
    }

    private void CreateListIndex(List list, string fieldName)
    {
        var field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);
        field.Indexed = true;
        field.Update();
        ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

The index on Title is added OK, but the other two fields fail with the following error:

> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Cannot complete this
>   action."

How can I add an index to these 2 fields?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I did not need to add an index to these fields... rather I updated to release 16 of the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientRuntime dlls (this is the version that supports SharePoint online) and then used the following methods instead of CAML queries:

- For the FileRef queries: clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl or clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl
- For the UniqueId queries: clientContext.Web.GetFolderById or clientContext.Web.GetFileById

NB the update from version 15 to version 16 of the dlls was only necessary to use the GetFolderById and GetFileById methods.